# Sending Mail in Windows forms?

Tags: c#

In windows Forms i write a code for sending mail, i place the mail settings in app.config, can you check my code please. is it correct or not.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="someaddress@mydomain.com">
    <network host="mail.mydomain.com" password="xxxxxx" port="25" userName="someaddress@mydomain.com"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

```
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        msg.To.Add(txtTO.Text);
        msg.From = new MailAddress("suryasasidhar13@gmail.com");
        msg.Body = txtDescription.Text;

        System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mMailSettings=null ;
        string mMailHost = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;

        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(mMailHost);
        mailClient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: What has this got to do with Windows Forms?

Comment: You set `mMailSettings` to `null`, but you are calling its child elements?

Comment: i am getting error,   System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mMailSettings;
            string mMailHost = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;

Comment: @Suryasasidhar Yes, that's because every variable in C# must be initialized before it is used. But you don't need to pass mail settings around in code - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want SmtpClient to use `mailSettings` from app.config, you should use its parameterless constructor - i.e. do not specify any settings in code. That way, SmtpClient will try to configure itself automatically based on app.config settings which seems to be exactly what you want.